# AngularJS Service losing values between routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I have 2 different controllers accessing the same service. One of the controllers, `search.ctrl.js` is visible on every page (the search bar at the top of the page) and the other controller is for a specific partial which displays the results of the search in a table.

The problem that I am having is that the service is setting the values properly after the search form is submitted, and those values are passed back to the controller properly, but then when I call `$location.path('/');` the values are no longer set in the service.

Whether this is the correct method or not, all I want is to be able to have a search bar on every page which uses the same html/js/css code, and the results of the search can be accessed from a particular page. Feel free to suggest alternative solutions, but my preferred answer would be one that fixes this one because I have read that it is usually best to use services for sharing data between views.

When viewing the following code keep in mind that it is the `documents` which I am wanting to access from multiple views.

Cheers :)

**Controllers**

**`search.ctrl.js`**

```
angular.module("app").controller("SearchController", 
  function($scope, $location, DocumentSearch){
    $scope.title = "Some title";
    $scope.doctypes = [
                       {type: "doc", checked: true},
                       {type: "docx", checked: true},
                       {type: "xls", checked: true},
                       {type: "xlsx", checked: true},
                       {type: "txt", checked: true}];

    $scope.checkAll = true;
    $scope.searching = false;
    $scope.showSearchPanel = function(){
        $scope.searching = !$scope.searching;
    };
    $scope.checkOrUncheckAll = function(checkAll){
        $scope.checkAll = checkAll;
        setValueOfAllCheckBoxes($scope.checkAll);
    };

    $scope.someSelected = function (doctypes) {
        for (var d in doctypes){
            console.log(doctypes[d]);
            if (doctypes[d].checked)
                return true;
        }

        return "You must select a checkbox";
    };

    $scope.search = function(documentTitle, checkAll){
        if (atLeastOneCheckBoxIsSelected()){
            $scope.error = null;
            $scope.documents = DocumentSearch.search(documentTitle, 
                               getSelectedCheckBoxes());
            $location.path("home");
        } else {
            $scope.documents = null;
            $scope.error = "Please select at least one file type.";
        }
    };

    function setValueOfAllCheckBoxes(isChecked){
        for (var d in $scope.doctypes){
            $scope.doctypes[d].checked = isChecked;
        }
    }

    function atLeastOneCheckBoxIsSelected(){
        return (getSelectedCheckBoxes().length > 0);
    }

    function getSelectedCheckBoxes(){
        return $scope.doctypes.filter(function(obj){
            return obj.checked;
        });
    }

});
```

**`main.ctrl.js`**

```
angular.module("app").controller("MainController", 
    function($scope, $location, DocumentSearch){
        $scope.documents = DocumentSearch.documents;
        console.log(DocumentSearch);
});
```

**`search.ser.js`**

```
angular.module("app").factory("DocumentSearch", function(){

    var search = function(title, doctypes){
        return searchExample(title, doctypes);
    };

    function getDocumentExtention(checked){

        checked.sort( function(){ return 0.5 - Math.random(); } );

        return checked[0].type;
    }

    console.log("SOMETHING");
    var documents = searchExample("Example document", [{type: "txt", checked: true}]);

    function searchExample(title, doctypes){
        documents = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            documents.push({
                documentTitle: title + " " + i + "." + getDocumentExtention(doctypes),
                documentID: i * 111111111,
                documentStatus: "Available",
                documentVersionDate: "15:32:254 18/11/2015",
                documentFileModified: "15:35:974 18/11/2015",
                documentCheckedOutUserID: "8276",
                documentCheckedOutUsername: "joshuaBrass1"
            });
        }

        return documents;
    }

    return {
        search: search,
        documents: documents
    };
});
```

Comment: What I have understood is, through the global search you want to search for a document, get it stored in some $scope variable in search.ctrl.js. now when you go to main.ctrl.js you want to get searched document there through your document.ser.js service. The problem is you search through global search (its working), go to main.ctrl.js but not getting that searched document data. Is it correct?

Comment: I would try to use a var returns { search: search, documents: documents} and then return it: return returns;

Comment: I want to get the value from the Service. The service is shared between the search controller and the main controller. The search controller populates the values in the Service and the main controller reads and displays them.

If that is not a good solution please explain why and provide an alternative suggestion